# Jquery off-line configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My basic website uses a css template using the jQuery.

When i'm off-line, the menu of my website does not appear like when i'm online. I think, that there is a piece of code that download some Jquery-codes. I never learned the Jquery. It will be great if you can help to specify the codes that uses an extern code so i can download it et fix it.

Here is the different files in the folder named "js" : `jquery.dropotron.js`, `jquery.dropotron.min.js`, `html5shiv.js,skel.min.js`. I don't know if i should attach the codes associated.

thanks

Comment: It is missing resource needed from another web location. You must supply the source of your page head section and the most bottom section if there are any `js` or `css` files there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to not depend on external resources so that your app still work in offline mode.

Generally that means that you can download the dependencies and store them locally as opposed to requesting them from the internet.

As an example you can change the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Removing jquery version from internet -->
<!-- with a locally hosted version of jQuery plugin -->
<!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> -->

<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body class="middle-school-region-1">

  <p>some text</p>
  <p>more text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. I have fixed it like you recommend. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it you are getting jQuery from an external location. You probably have something like this:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
```

This loads jquery in from the internet. You can download it and link to a locally saved version.